# Hard disk has space, but I can't transfer a file to it?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, debug

I've got an external hard disk that has 147 GB of free storage left, but when I try to transfer a file to it, it gives an error:

[image]

What's causing the error?

How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem of the external drive may be FAT32.  (Windows doesn't like to format drives as large as yours as FAT32, but it may have been formatted that way at the factory). The largest size file FAT32 supports is 4GB.  You will need to convert the filesystem to NTFS to support files larger than 4GB.

Here are instructions on how to do this: [How to convert FAT32 to NTFS in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11106-convert-fat-fat32-volume-ntfs.html)
These steps will work in XP and Vista as well (in XP or Windows 2000, just ignore where it says to use an elevated command prompt - as long as you're an administrator it will work)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your drive is formatted in FAT32...

"The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GiB minus 1 byte or 4 294 967 295 (232−1) bytes. Video applications, large databases, and some other software easily exceed this limit. Larger files require another filesystem."

Source [Wikipedia Fat32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)

Comment: so what's my solution?

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned, FAT32 does not support files bigger then 4GB. Convert your HDD to NTFS or split the file to smaller parts - you can use something like 7Zip or some file splitter. Other solution is to use some video conversion utility like Avidemux and create two separate parts of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Hana Kimi is too large for the drive. Use the convert command to change it to NTFS. Go to Start > Run, and type:

cmd

In the command window, type:

convert driveletter: /fs:ntfs
(where "driveletter:" is the letter of your external drive followed by a colon)

This will take a while to complete.

Then it will take all of Hana Kimi and more. Make sure you back up files you want to keep. You should have at least 2 copies in different locations. Hard drives all fail unless they are not used.